# Java 8 map list to map of lists by key

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following Java code:

```
List<BaseQuery> queries; 

Map<Long, List<BaseQuery>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (BaseQuery query : queries) {
    List<BaseQuery> queryList = map.get(query.getCharacteristicId());
    if(queryList == null) {
        queryList = new ArrayList<>();
        map.put(query.getCharacteristicId(), queryList);
    }
    queryList.add(query);
}
```

Could you please show how to convert it to Java 8 and streams?

Comment: Hey :) Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: `Map<Long, List<BaseQuery>> map = queries.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(BaseQuery::getCharacteristicId));`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: you can delete your own question btw...

Comment: @Eugene no, this question can't be deleted right now by me due to SO rules

Comment: why on earth did you edit it like this? what was wrong with leaving it open?

Comment: Can we know reasons why you want to delete this question? If it is caused by negative votes you can always ask mods to remove this question from your profile.

Comment: @Pshemo I did it already

Comment: Then what is the problem with reverting it to its original form? Decision if question will be removed from your profile isn't really related to how it looks like now. Would you mind rolling it back to version which contained real question?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is as simple as `groupingBy`:

```
queries.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(BaseQuery::getCharacteristicId));
```

This will create a `List<BaseQuery>` as value, it is implicitly:

```
queries.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            BaseQuery::getCharacteristicId,
            Collectors.toList()));
```

But if you want guarantees of a mutable `List`:

```
queries.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            BaseQuery::getCharacteristicId,
            Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
```

Answer (score 0):

In java 8 , you can do as @Eugene's answer. And in java 7,you can use **org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils** as follow:

```
List<String> idList = (List<String>) CollectionUtils.collect(objectList, 
                                new BeanToPropertyValueTransformer("id"));
```